# Can anyone help me convert this HOC to Render Prop

Tags: reactjs, redux

I have seen blogs stating all HOCs can be converted to Render Props.

I have this HOC in our Code. I'm wondering if this can be converted to render prop.

This is a Connected HOC.

```
import React from 'react';
import { compose } from 'redux';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { modes } from '../../../modes';


const Wrapper = Component => (props) => {
  const { mode, ...rest } = props;
  if (mode === modes.VIEW) {
    return (<Component
      {...rest}
      disabled
    />);
  }

  return (<Component
    {...rest}
  />);
};

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  mode: state.mode,
});

const composedHOC = compose(
  connect(mapStateToProps, null),
  Wrapper
);

export default composedHOC
;
```

Comment: https://reactrocket.com/post/turn-your-hocs-into-render-prop-components/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are talking about [this pattern](https://reactjs.org/docs/render-props.html), then I'd say this is how to do it.

Wrapper:

```
const WrapperBase = props =>
   props.mode === 'VIEW' ? 
      props.render({...props, disabled: true}) : 
      props.render({...props});

// using same mapStateToProps as in your HOC
const Wrapper = connect(mapStateToProps, null)(WrapperBase);
export default Wrapper;
```

Usage:

```
<Wrapper render={({disabled}) => <div>disabled: {disabled ? 'true' : 'false'}</div>}/>
```

Unit Test:

```
describe('Wrapper', () => {
  it('should pass the disabled prop to the inner component', () => {
    const options = {context: {}, childContextTypes: {}};
    const state = {mode: 'VIEW'};
    Wrapper = setStore(options, () => state)(Wrapper);
    const i = mount(<Wrapper render={({disabled}) => <div>disabled: {disabled ? 'true' : 'false'}</div>}/>, options);
    expect(i.html()).toBe('<div>disabled: true</div>');
  });
});
```

Note that I used the string `VIEW` as I don't have your `modes.js` file.